# matching regular expression {*} in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to match a name with itself plus a possible suffix using the `{*}` regular expression in a TCL script. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set name "g_renamed_d"
set pattern "g_renamed*"
if {  [string match "$name" "$pattern"]} {
    puts " matched!" 
} else {
    puts " not matched!!!!!"
}
```

When that did not work I tried removing the star from the pattern variable and using `[string match "$name" "$pattern"*]` or `[string match $name $pattern*]` or `[string match $name {$pattern*}]` but all to no avail. I have seen other examples which seem identical to what I did; what am I missing?

Comment: The syntax for [`string match`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35) is **string match ?option? pattern string**. Regex is something else and uses **regexp pattern string ?match? ?submatch1? ...**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set name "g_renamed_d"
set pattern "^g_renamed.*"
if {[regexp $pattern $name match]} {
    puts " matched! :)" 
    puts $match
} else {
    puts " not matched! :("
}
```

Note that the pattern above allows all kinds of characters including white spaces except newlines. If you want a more "reasonable" pattern, you can replace the comma with a character class with the characters you allow in the suffix:

```
set pattern "^g_renamed[a-z0-9_]*" # all "word" character (the same as \w)
```

or

```
set pattern "^g_renamed\S*"    # all that is not a white space
```

But this pattern is suffisant if you want only check that your string begins with your target:

```
set pattern "^g_renamed"
```

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up the `glob`-style star with the regular expressions (Kleene) star.

In regular expressions, `*` does not mean "a string of any characters," as is the case in `glob`-style usages. `*`, `+`, and `?` are all known as **quantifiers**, respectively meaning "0 or more", "1 or more", and "0 or 1" repetitions of ***the preceding atom (character)***.

So, for example, `*` by itself does nothing, but `a*` matches 0 or more `a`s.

To match 0 or more *anything*, you want to put a quantifier on a **wildcard**, which in regular expressions is `.`, meaning "any character except newline characters." That is why, as @CasimiretHippolyte noted in his answer first, you'd want `g_renamed.*`.

Also, the way `regexp` matching works is that it returns `true` if the pattern matches *anywhere* in the string. That is, the name, `foog_renamedbar` would pass too! That's where @CasimiretHippolyte has suggested the use of an **anchor**, `^`, which matches the very beginning of the string, *i.e.* the pattern is *anchored* to the start of the string. (Similarly, `$` is another anchor, this one matching the *end* of the string.)

---

By the way, if you truly want `glob`-style matching, then use [`string match`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35).

Answer (score 0):

Your doing reverse comparision. Just change the content it will work. Like
trigger off;
tcl;

```
eval {
    set pattern "g_renamed_d"
    set name "g_renamed*"
    if { [string match -nocase "$name" "$pattern"] } {  
        puts " matched!" 
    } else {
        puts " not matched!!!!!"
    }       
}
```

Comment: You don't need quotes around a variable if it is by itself. Thus `string match -nocase $name $pattern` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Also why `eval`?